# Conformal and chiral anomalies

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, quantum-anomalies

In presentation [On conformal anomalies
of some 6d superconformal theories](http://theor.jinr.ru/sqs15/Talks/Tseytlin.pdf) was mentioned that there are some **relations between chiral/gravitational and conformal anomalies**.

For me, it is very nontrivial, beacause conformal and chiral symmetries/anomalies have different nature.

Could somebody explain such relation?